# Issue with xpath / regex in Scrapy spider

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract a product id from an onclick tag within a "preceding-sibling" which is a ul tag (id="ShowProductImages").

The number I'm trying to extract is directly after ?pid=, example:

...list/ViewAll?pid=**234565**&image=206...

Below is the content that I'm trying to extract from:

```
<ul id="ShowProductImages" class="imageView">
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" onClick="javascript:initWindow('http://products.example.com/products/list/ViewAll?pid=234565&amp;image=754550',520,520,100,220);return false;"><img src="http://content.example.com/assets/images/products/j458jk.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="Product image description here" border="0"></a></li>        
</ul>

<div class="description">
    Description here...
</div>
```

I am using xpath to select the onclick tag along with a regular expression to extract the id. This is the code I'm using (which is not working)

```
def parse(self, response):
  sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
  products_path = sel.xpath('//div[@class="description"]')
  for product_path in products_path:
   product = Product()
   product['product_pid'] = product_path.xpath('preceding-sibling::ul[@id="ShowProductImages"][1]//li/a[1]/@onclick').re(r'(?:pid=)(.+?)(?:\'|$)')
   yield product
```

Any suggestions? I'm not quite sure where I went wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try this, selecting from the `ul`, and testing its `<div class="description">` sibling in a predicate:

```
sel.xpath("""//ul[following-sibling::div[@class="description"]]
                 [@id="ShowProductImages"]
                 /li/a[1]/@onclick""").re(r'(?:pid=)(\d+)')
```

I changed your regular expression to restrict to digits.

Comment: You could probably also restrict the regex to `re(r'pid=(\d+)')`, non selective parenthesis are useless here...